# iPhone OpenGLES texture loading issue with transparency

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, textures, transparent

I've been using this method (I think I got it from one of Apple's example code projects):

```
- (void)loadTexture:(NSString *)name intoLocation:(GLuint)location
{ 
 CGImageRef textureImage = [UIImage imageNamed:name].CGImage;

 if(textureImage == nil)
 {
  NSLog(@"Failed to load texture!");
  return;
 }

 NSInteger texWidth = CGImageGetWidth(textureImage);
 NSInteger texHeight = CGImageGetHeight(textureImage);
 GLubyte *textureData = (GLubyte *)malloc(texWidth * texHeight * 4);
 CGContextRef textureContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(textureData,
              texWidth,
              texHeight,
              8,
              texWidth * 4,
              CGImageGetColorSpace(textureImage),
              kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

 //The Fix:
 //CGContextClearRect(textureContext, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, texWidth, texHeight));

 CGContextDrawImage(textureContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, (float)texWidth, (float)texHeight), textureImage);
 CGContextRelease(textureContext);

 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, location);
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

 free(textureData);

 glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
 glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
}
```

I then load in my textures like so in the `initWithCoder` method:

```
glGenTextures(NUM_OF_TEXTURES, &textures[0]);
[self loadTexture:@"1.png" intoLocation:textures[0]];
[self loadTexture:@"2.png" intoLocation:textures[1]];
[self loadTexture:@"3.png" intoLocation:textures[2]];
[self loadTexture:@"4.png" intoLocation:textures[3]];
[self loadTexture:@"5.png" intoLocation:textures[4]];
```

Now this works great for me, but when the images loaded contain transparent areas, they will show the previous images behind them.

For example, if all five images have transparent areas on them:

- 1.png will show as it should.
- 2.png will show with 1.png in the background.
- 3.png will show with 2.png in the background with 1.png in the background.
- etc...

I thought this would be in my drawing code, but even when I disable GL_BLEND this still happens. I am drawing using vertex arrays using `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`.

EDIT: Further explanation

Here are the 3 textures I'm using in my game:

[image]

Using the code to load the textures and after binding them and drawing, this is what happens:

[image]

Surely this is not transparency functioning as intended. If anyone could help that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: That's transparency functioning as intended - letting you see through to the layers beneath. I'm not sure what the question is here.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it easier to understand. The second image is what happens when I bind each texture. So for 'Img 3' I would only be looking for the red square to draw and for 'Img 2' - the green one to draw, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem. You need to clear the CGContextRef before drawing the texture into it. It just happens to hold the last image, it could just as well be uninitialized memory or something.

```
CGContextClearRect( cgContext, CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f, width, height ) );
```

Call this right before your `CGContextDrawImage`.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why that wasn't included in the example I used. Solved my problemo anyway :)